Adding accuracy, recall and f1 metrics to SFTTrainer
I'm working on fine tuning an LLM using SFTTrainer.
For some reason, during validation phase it only yields the eval_loss.
While this is nice, I actually interested also on other metrics (accuracy for example), but I wasn't able to figure out yet how to do it.
I've seen many examples for Trainer class and I know SFTTrainer supports compute_metrics parameter in its __init__ method, but I had no luck in actually connect all the pieces together.
A quick look found some the below issues on GitHub:https://github.com/huggingface/trl/issues/862 and https://github.com/huggingface/trl/issues/862
For what its worth, my dataset is formatted as follows:

Train ==> prompt + data + response
Evaluation ==> prompt + data + response  (I'm aware the response should be removed)
Test ==> prompt + data

Here's where the trainer is being created:

    def create_trainer(self):
        train_args = TrainingArguments(
            per_device_train_batch_size=2,
            gradient_accumulation_steps=2,
            warmup_steps=200,
            gradient_checkpointing=True,
            per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
            # num_train_epochs=self.num_of_epochs,
            max_steps=10,
            learning_rate=2e-4,
            fp16=not is_bfloat16_supported(),
            bf16=is_bfloat16_supported(),
            logging_steps=1,
            optim="adamw_8bit",
            weight_decay=0.01,
            lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
            report_to="none",
            seed=3407,
            output_dir=self.output_dir,
            eval_strategy="steps",
            eval_steps=0.1,
        )

        trainer = SFTTrainer(
            model=self.model,
            compute_metrics=self.compute_metrics,
            preprocess_logits_for_metrics=self.preprocess_logits_for_metrics,
            tokenizer=self.tokenizer,
            train_dataset=self.train_data,
            eval_dataset=self.eval_data,
            dataset_text_field="text",
            max_seq_length=self.max_seq_length,
            dataset_num_proc=2,
            packing=False,  # Can make training 5x faster for short sequences.
            args=train_args,
            dataset_kwargs={
                "add_special_tokens": False,
                "append_concat_token": False,
            }
        )

        return trainer

and also
    @staticmethod
    def preprocess_logits_for_metrics(logits, labels):
        """
        Original Trainer may have a memory leak.
        This is a workaround to avoid storing too many tensors that are not needed.
        """
        pred_ids = torch.argmax(logits[0], dim=-1)
        return pred_ids, labels

    @staticmethod
    def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
        # Unpack predictions and labels
        predictions, _ = eval_pred.predictions
        labels = eval_pred.label_ids

        # Flatten labels if necessary
        if labels.ndim > 1:
            labels = labels.flatten()

        # Ensure predictions are in the same format
        if predictions.ndim > 1:
            predictions = predictions.flatten()

        # Remove invalid labels if necessary (e.g., -100)
        valid_indices = labels != -100

        # Handle size mismatch if needed
        if len(predictions) != len(labels):
            # You might need to slice or pad arrays here
            min_len = min(len(predictions), len(labels))
            labels = labels[:min_len]
            predictions = predictions[:min_len]
            valid_indices = valid_indices[:min_len]

        # Filter out invalid indices
        labels = labels[valid_indices]
        predictions = predictions[valid_indices]

        # Calculate accuracy, precision, recall, and F1 score
        accuracy = accuracy_score(labels, predictions)
        precision, recall, f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(labels, predictions, average='weighted')

        return {
            'accuracy': accuracy,
            'precision': precision,
            'recall': recall,
            'f1': f1,
        }

